# dtrace how to get socket type in syscall::write:

Tags: dtrace

I want to trace bytes written to a socket.

I know I can get `fileinfo_t` from `fds[arg0]`.

Is there a way to get type of a socket in `syscall::write:`?

How can I safely transfer this information from `syscall::write:entry` to `syscall::write:return` to count bytes written?

Comment: Why do you need to transfer information to `syscall::write:return` to get the number of bytes written?  The return value of all the `syscall:::return` probes is passed in both `arg0` and `arg1`.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/chp-syscall-6/index.html

Comment: I meant I need to pass socket type information to return call to construct trace message.

Comment: You see I can handle entry and return calls separately.
E.g. I can have such log records

//entry trace message
Google Chrome 600 bytes writing /* some info about socket to which application is writing */
//return trace message
Google Chrome 567 bytes written                        

What I want is to have single record
Google Chrome 567 bytes written /* some info about socket to which application is writing */

So I need to somehow get socket information in entry call and pass it to return call.